# Error occurs when trying to convert nvarchar to date mssql node js

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, database

I'm trying to query a SQL Server from node js, using the `mssql` module. The date format in the database is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. The query works just fine from SQL Server Management Studio, but it generates the following error when used in node.js:

[image: the error generated]

Here is the code:

```
//This query aims to retrieve the records that have been inserted to the database in the last 5 min 
var sq = "SELECT * FROM [ofm1].[dbo].[ass_site] WHERE CONVERT(datetime, date1) > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE());"

conn = new mssql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

conn.connect().then(function () {
    var request = new mssql.Request(conn);

    request.query(sq).then(function (recordSet) {
         recordSet  = recordSet.recordset;
         recordSet = JSON.stringify(recordSet)
         recordSet = JSON.parse(recordSet)

         recordSet.forEach(function(row) {
             console.log("row:nevr:  "  + row.nevr)
             console.log("row:group id "  + row.codeass)

             var rq = new mssql.Request(conn);
             rq.input('id', mssql.NChar, row.nevr)
             rq.input('group', mssql.NChar, row.codeass)
             rq.input('feedback', mssql.Text, "new ticket !")
             rq.input('url', mssql.NChar, "")
             rq.input('notified', mssql.TinyInt, 0)

             rq.query("INSERT INTO [ofm1].[dbo].[ticket] values (@id, @group, @feedback, @url, @notified);").then(function() {
             });
        });

       /* console.log(recordSet);
       console.log("description: " + recordSet.name);*/
       // conn.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
       conn.close();
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually this error happens when trying to convert date not well formatted

for example try to convert date of format mm/dd/yyyy using dd/mm/yyyy format

```
SELECT  CONVERT(datetime, '06/18/2018 12:05:23',103)
```

result:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

but if it is well formatted as following will working fine

```
SELECT  CONVERT(datetime, '18/06/2018 12:05:23',103)
```

result:

> 2018-06-18 12:05:23.000

specify format code of your date to be `103` to match your date format `dd/mm/yyyy` as following:

```
//This query aims to retrieve the records that have been inserted to the database in the last 5 min 
var sq = "SELECT * FROM [ofm1].[dbo].[ass_site] WHERE CONVERT(datetime, date1,103) > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE());"
```

for more details about format code check following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)